# How to override translations per instance/installation?

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization

We have a symfony 2 project which is provided on-premises. 
Now one client is unhappy with the terminology of the app and wants to change it.

I know we can override translations using (https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/bundles/override.html#translations).
But of course we want to keep our source code clean, so we are looking for a method which doesn't affect our original code.

Is it possible to somehow define an additional translations-folder which can be excluded by .gitignore and override the default app/Resources/translations folder?

I want to add, that a fork of our project doesn't seem to be the right choice, since it would affect our development/deployment workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a new bundle, CustomTranslationsBundle, where my client can place his custom translation files without affecting version control.

Pretty basic, and I should have thought about that before asking my question...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need to edit translations in only one instance of your application.

Maybe you can use a Translation Bundle and store your keys into a Saas software.
Have a look at https://github.com/php-translation/symfony-bundle this mays help you

Comment: By instance, I mean a copy of our application which runs on an in-house server at our clients site. This copy gets updated automatically whenever we create a new release of our software. Not sure what you mean by Saas software? I'd prefer to have a simple file based translation. Like a folder named "custom-translations" where you can store yaml files, e.g. "AcmeCoreBundle.en.yml"